# What to do when the QMenu is too long

Tags: qt

I think we all meet this situation, when the menu is too long, or we just have too many menu items, the screen can't show all the items at a time. What could I do with Qt? There is a common solution with MFC, we add a new item in this menu, and hide some items temporarily, when user clicked this item, then show more items. Could anyone give me a good solution? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your menu design. Too many menu entries can be confusing and annoying.

Comment: You could do the same thing you did in MFC. Just remove some actions from the menu and add them on click...

Comment: @RedX Can you make the menu to stay open when the user clicked on this item? I'd guess that this will be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitively restructure your menu. Group similar items into a group of items using submenus. You shoudln't have more than (let's say) 15 items in one menu at a time.

For example:

```
Edit
    Delete
    Cut
    Copy
    Copy as vector graphics
    Copy as low resolution raster graphics
    Copy as high resolution raster graphics
    Copy as custom resolution raster graphics
    Copy text
    Paste
    Paste into new layer
    Paste into new document
    ...
```

could be restructured into

```
Edit
    Delete
    Cut
    Copy
    Copy as...
        Vector graphics
        Raster graphics
            Low resolution
            High resolution
            Custom...
        Text
    Paste
    Paste into...
        New layer
        New document
    ...
```